# Pass form data through url by setting in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have set a route in my Laravel project, if it was with href I would have done it like this `{{route('destination'),$country_from,$country_to}}` but now I want to pass in the form data as the `$country_from` and `$country_to` please how can I do this

```
<form action="{{route('destination')}}">
            @csrf
                        <input type="text"
                            class="search-form flexdatalist"
                            name="origin"
                            placeholder="country_from"
                            data-search-in='name'
                            data-min-length='1'
                            />


                        <img src="{{URL::asset('img/location.svg')}}" class="search-icon origin" width="28px" height="21px"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-3 mx-0 px-0">
                           <input type="text"
                                class="search-form flexdatalist"
                                name="country_to"
                                data-search-in='name'
                                data-min-length='1'
                                placeholder="Travelling to"

                            />
                            <img src="{{URL::asset('img/location.svg')}}" class="search-icon destination" width="28px" height="21px"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 mx-0 px-0">
                    <input type="text"
                                class="search-form flexdatalist"
                                name="residence"
                                data-search-in='name'
                                data-min-length='1'
                                placeholder="Residing In"

                            />
                            <img src="{{URL::asset('img/location.svg')}}" class="search-icon residence" width="28px" height="21px"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 px-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search Visas" class="btn btn-primary search-btn"/>
                        </form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{country_from}/{country_to}',  'DestinationCountriesController@index')->name('destination');
```

Comment: You're going to need javascript to take the values the user inputs and link if that's the route you want.

Comment: Or.. submit the form to a separate route that then redirects to the destination route using the submitted parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do:

You want to redirect the user to the URL after form submit, and use form values in the redirection URL?

- In your form POST controller, retrieve inputs from $request and return a `return redirect()->route('route_name', ['country_from' => $request->country_from, 'country_to' => $request->country_to])`

You want to use URL values as input values, so on page load, inputs are filled with URL values?

- Your "destination" route controller method accepts as parameter `$country_from` and `$country_to` as you declared those variables with your route. You so have those variables in your controller, you can sanitize them, bind them to the returned view (eg: `return view('view', $data)` or `return view('view', compact('country_from', 'country_to'))`), and accessed it as usual in your blade.
- You can also access URL values using `\Request::route('country_from')`. You should sanitize this values before using it as input.
- use those variables in your blade as input `value` attributes, or `placeholder`, anywhere `{{$country_to}}`.

Comment: It redirected with and it's showing this url `http://localhost:8000/destination?_token=xKY7QEzceYP6zdYrtnNriOgbBbs9izeBeE6GyDQl&origin=Nigeria&flexdatalist-origin=Nigeria&country_to=Australia&residence=United+Arab+Emirates` not `/Nigeria/United+Arab+Emirates`

Comment: What is the thing you're trying to achieve ? First or second ?

Comment: second, am tryng to achieve the second

Comment: If it's the second, I don't get where the redirection happens. As second is about using URL values as input values in your blade.

Comment: This is the code based on your answer `public function reroute(Request $request)
    {
     $country_from = $request->country_from;
     $country_to = $request->country_to;
        redirect()->route('/{country_from}/{country_to}', ['country_from' => $country_from,
            'country_to' => $country_to]);
    }`

Comment: `/{country_from}/{country_to}` is wrong, it should be your route name here. As I indicated `return redirect()->route('route_name'...`. Also the `redirect()` must be returned.

Comment: with the route name there, it comes out with the same outcome

Comment: Hum I just tested, and the URL is correct in the end... Could you `php artisan route:list` to check your route name ? and put the full code again ?